# paste new column based on value in a text string

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
speech <- c("N_28.5", "CH1_20", "CH2_33.4")
overlaps <- c("Body_N_20; Hands_CH1_5", "Body_CH1_10; Hands_CH2_3", "Body_CH2_44; Hands_N_30; Hands_N_3" )

df <- data.frame(speech, overlaps)
```

Which produces a data frame that looks like this:

| speech | overlaps |
| --- | --- |
| N_28.5 | Body_N_20;Hands_CH1_5 |
| CH2_33.4 | Body_CH1_10; Hands_CH2_3 |
| CH1_20 | Body_CH2_44; Hands_N_30; Hands_N_3 |

I want a function that looks at the numerical values in the 'overlaps' column. If that value is at greater than or equal to HALF of the value of the numerical value in 'speech', I want paste the associated text in the another column.

Thus, the output should look something like this:

| speech | overlaps | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N_28.5 | Body_N_20; Hands_CH1_5 | Body_N |
| CH2_33.4 | Body_CH1_10; Hands_CH2_3 | Body_CH1 |
| CH1_20 | Body_CH2_44; Hands_N_30; Hands_N_3 | Body_CH2; Hands_N |

I figure I'll need some regex to capture the numbers, but I'm having trouble coming with how to do a if X then do Y with logical operators.

Comment: I believe you mixed the output of row 3 nd 2. please check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `strsplit()` to separate `overlaps` into a list of vectors, `mapply()` to filter each vector based on your test, then `paste()`ing back together:

```r
df$target <- mapply(
  \(sp, ov) paste(
    sub("_\\d+\\.?\\d*$", "", ov)[
      as.numeric(sub(".*_(\\d+\\.?\\d*$)", "\\1", ov)) >= 
      as.numeric(sub(".*_(\\d+\\.?\\d*$)", "\\1", sp)) / 2
    ],
    collapse = "; "
  ),
  df$speech,
  strsplit(df$overlaps, "; ")
)
```

Result:

```
#> df
    speech                           overlaps            target
1   N_28.5             Body_N_20; Hands_CH1_5            Body_N
2   CH1_20           Body_CH1_10; Hands_CH2_3          Body_CH1
3 CH2_33.4 Body_CH2_44; Hands_N_30; Hands_N_3 Body_CH2; Hands_N
```

As an alternative, here’s a tidyverse-based approach that separates your data into one row per `overlaps` value and assigns a flag for whether each row meets the criterion. This might be easier to work with than keeping it as a single delimited string, depending on what you’re doing next.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(overlaps, delim = "; ") %>%
  mutate(
    is_target = as.numeric(str_extract(overlaps, "\\d+\\.?\\d*$")) >= 
                as.numeric(str_extract(speech, "\\d+\\.?\\d*$")) / 2
  )
```

Result:

```
    speech    overlaps is_target
1   N_28.5   Body_N_20      TRUE
2   N_28.5 Hands_CH1_5     FALSE
3   CH1_20 Body_CH1_10      TRUE
4   CH1_20 Hands_CH2_3     FALSE
5 CH2_33.4 Body_CH2_44      TRUE
6 CH2_33.4  Hands_N_30      TRUE
7 CH2_33.4   Hands_N_3     FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this approach will apply to your use-case, but another potential option is to 'split' the columns with multiple values into 'one value per column', then apply your criteria to select the rows of interest, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

speech <- c("N_28.5", "CH1_20", "CH2_33.4")
overlaps <- c("Body_N_20; Hands_CH1_5", "Body_CH1_10; Hands_CH2_3", "Body_CH2_44; Hands_N_30; Hands_N_3" )

df <- data.frame(speech, overlaps)

df %>%
  separate_rows(overlaps, sep = "; ") %>%
  mutate(across(c("speech", "overlaps"),
                ~parse_number(str_remove(.x, ".*_")),
                .names = "{.col}_numeric"),
         across(c("speech", "overlaps"),
                ~str_remove(.x, "_[^_]+$"),
                .names = "{.col}_category")) %>%
  filter(overlaps_numeric >= (speech_numeric / 2)) %>%
  rename(target = overlaps_category) %>%
  select(-c(speech_numeric, speech_category, overlaps_numeric))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   speech   overlaps    target  
#>   <chr>    <chr>       <chr>   
#> 1 N_28.5   Body_N_20   Body_N  
#> 2 CH1_20   Body_CH1_10 Body_CH1
#> 3 CH2_33.4 Body_CH2_44 Body_CH2
#> 4 CH2_33.4 Hands_N_30  Hands_N
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>